# How to retrieve instance of repository which implements JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently facing an issue in a work project.

From a string parameter passed in a controller representing a sql table name (e.g: TABLE_NAME), i must extract all the data from it. Not all the tables are eligible, only 7.

I thought about that:

1. create custom annotation with a `tableName` parameter (`@SpiderExtract` in my implementation)
2. annotate all the repos eligible with it
3. from a service, build a `Map` where k is the table name as a string and v is the repository instance
4. then `map.get("TABLE_NAME")` to get the correct repo and start doing my stuff

The problem is that the repositories instances within the hashmap are of type `SimpleJpaRepository`, with this implementation, I have no access to my custom queries (which i understand) only classic one (findAll(), findById() ...)

My repositories are declared like the following:

```java
@SpiderExtract(tableName = "TABLE_NAME")
@Repository
public class RepoFoo implements JpaRepository<Foo, Long>{

@Query(value = "select * from foo")
List<Foo> getFoos();
}
```

This is what i've tried so far:

```
private Map<String, JpaRepository<?, ?>> reposSpiderEligible() {
return applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(SpiderExtract.class).values().stream()
        .filter(repository -> repository instanceof JpaRepository)
        .map(repository -> (JpaRepository<?, ?>) repository)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(repository -> {
            Class<?> repositoryInterface = repository.getClass().getInterfaces()[0];
            SpiderExtract annotation = repositoryInterface.getAnnotation(SpiderExtract.class);
            return annotation.tableName();
        }, Function.identity()));
```

}

How to get the `RepoFoo` instance instead of a `SimpleJpaRepository` instance ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Since you only have 7 tables for this purpose why not do it the simple way? Create a factory and based on the table name you provide it with the repo/method you need? Or if you want to pursue this annotation path anyways why not just annotate the specific method for each of the repositories and get them instead? This way you don't need to worry which specific method you want as you already know because of the annotation.

Comment: Thanks you @JorgeCampos for your answer :). I have thought about implementing a factory which returns instance of a particular repository based on table string in a switch case statement. Don't you think think that's a dirty way to implement it ? I mean the switch/case statement will be hard to maintinain imo.

Comment: The design pattern Factory is there since forever, so are you calling a well established pattern a dirty implementation? And to answer you, no I don't think so. This requirement of yours is already violating a separation of concerns principle the application front end/api parameters knows about the ins/outs of your backend (tables). And about the maintainability statement of yours, you really think that a switch case would be harder to maintain and understand than `reposSpiderEligible` method? Write the switch and then compare which one is harder to read :)

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer @JorgeCampos ! I have only two years of professional development experience. I will follow your advice then. Thanks for your time :).

Comment: No worries, also you can implement a factory without a switch if you really don't like it, here is an example: https://medium.com/swlh/factory-pattern-without-switch-this-is-how-it-should-be-done-cd895e356f44